# What is wrong with ddebs.ubuntu.com

Tags: apt, gnupg, debug, signature

Did something expire that should not have?

I am using debug symbols on my Ubuntu 20.10 install, and now I get this when I run the `apt-get update` command.

```
W: An error occurred during the signature verification. The repository is not updated and the previous index files will be used.
GPG error: http://ddebs.ubuntu.com groovy Release: The following signatures were invalid:
EXPKEYSIG C8CAB6595FDFF622 Ubuntu Debug Symbol Archive Automatic Signing Key (2016) <ubuntu-archive@lists.ubuntu.com>
```

Comment: If you go to Show Applications and select Additional Drivers does this resource show on the Other Software tab? Can you show us the full path if it does?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a current bug, see here for info and workaround:
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ubuntu-keyring/+bug/1920640/comments/3

Quoting from the above post, run:

> ```
> $ sudo wget -O- http://ddebs.ubuntu.com/dbgsym-release-key.asc | sudo apt-key add -
> $ sudo apt update
> ```

Answer (score 1):

You have to follow the https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Debug%20Symbol%20Packages precisely.

You probably missed the following step:

```
sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys F2EDC64DC5AEE1F6B9C621F0C8CAB6595FDFF622
```

Then run `sudo apt update`.

Comment: Nope. I already did that a long time ago, and it was always working. It just recently stopped working.